# Multiples Footer CallBack en Datatables

Tags: api, datatables

Tengo la necesidad de poner 3 datos en footer de datatables. Estoy usando Footer CallBack de datatables. La idea es poner el subtotal, propinas y total (suma de subtotal y propina).
En la imagen adjunta se puede ver como es[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo html:

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5" style="text-align:right">Sub Total:</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5" style="text-align:right">Propina(10%):</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

codigo js:

```
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 4 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(

                ('$'+number_format(pageTotal))
        }
```

como siempre, gracias a todos lo que puedan ayudar u orientarme en como poder realizar esto.
saludos.

Answer (score 0):

He llegado a esta pregunta buscando lo mismo, y he encontrado que por lo que parece con la api tal cual no puedes rellenar otras filas de una manera que pudiera parecer lógica como:

```
$(this.api().row(1).column(0).footer()).html('Propina');
```

Pero sí se puede conseguir de otra manera, pongo mi código como ejemplo:

**HTML:**

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
footerCallback: function (tfoot) {
    var total = this.api().ajax.json().total;
    //ROW 0
    $(this.api().column(0).footer()).html('TOTAL:');
    $(this.api().column(1).footer()).html(total[2]);
    $(this.api().column(2).footer()).html(total[0]);
    $(this.api().column(3).footer()).html(total[1]);
    $(this.api().column(4).footer()).html(total[3]);
    $(this.api().column(5).footer()).html();
    //ROW 1
    this.api().context[0].aoFooter[1][0].cell.innerHTML = 'FC | PPTO: ';
    this.api().context[0].aoFooter[1][1].cell.innerHTML = total[4] + ' | ' + total[5];
    this.api().context[0].aoFooter[1][2].cell.innerHTML = 'FCvsPPTO';
    this.api().context[0].aoFooter[1][3].cell.innerHTML = (total[4] - total[5]);
    this.api().context[0].aoFooter[1][4].cell.innerHTML = 'VARIACIÓN';
    this.api().context[0].aoFooter[1][5].cell.innerHTML = (((total[4] - total[5])/total[5])*100).toFixed(0)+'%';
},
```

La fila 0 también se podría poner así:

```
//ROW 0
this.api().context[0].aoFooter[0][0].cell.innerHTML = 'TOTAL:';
this.api().context[0].aoFooter[0][1].cell.innerHTML = total[2];
this.api().context[0].aoFooter[0][2].cell.innerHTML = total[0];
this.api().context[0].aoFooter[0][3].cell.innerHTML = total[1];
this.api().context[0].aoFooter[0][4].cell.innerHTML = total[3];
this.api().context[0].aoFooter[0][5].cell.innerHTML = '';
```